# Constant with multiple values?

Tags: vb.net, constants

I've stumbled upon that particular bit of code and i'm a bit stumped as the usefulness of it.

```
Public Const FILE_SHARE_READ as Integer = 1  
Public Const FILE_SHARE_WRITE as Integer = 2  
Public Const FILE_SHARE_DELETE as Integer = 4  
Public Const FILE_SHARE_ALL as Integer = FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE or FILE_SHARE_DELETE
```

i tested it a bit and haven't gotten any more insight than :
FILE_SHARE_ALL is always equal to 4 anyways.
Is there something i'm missing?

**EDIT**: Thanks for your help, i've found out the problem -> **Code 18**
Copy-paste mistake in my tester the line was

```
Public Const FILE_SHARE_ALL as Integer = FILE_SHARE_DELETE or FILE_SHARE_DELETE or FILE_SHARE_DELETE
```

Don't judge me!

Comment: it is combining "flags" so to speak. 1 2 and 4 are their own bits in binary, and "or"ing them together creates an integer with all flags represented.

Comment: Are you sure it's 4? it should be 7.

Comment: [If it is not 7, your VS is broke](https://dotnetfiddle.net/H9TQN6)

Comment: if i really screwed and someone posted an answer that would have fixed the problem if i had an actual problem other than a brainfart, should i trash the question or leave it there for prosperity?

Comment: Copy & paste mistakes are sometimes the hardest to find... I know a lot of programmers, each have their own story about the problem that took an entire day to solve and turned out to be nothing more then a copy-paste mistake, including myself... :-)

Comment: as an aside, shouldnt it be a bitwise AND if it's additive?

Comment: Nope. a bitwise AND of 1, 2 and 4 is 0, they are all on different bits.

Comment: with a little hindsight, blurry memories from my maths statistics classes say you are right. lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Public Const FILE_SHARE_READ as Integer = 1  
Public Const FILE_SHARE_WRITE as Integer = 2  
Public Const FILE_SHARE_DELETE as Integer = 4  
Public Const FILE_SHARE_ALL as Integer = FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE or FILE_SHARE_DELETE
```

The `Or` here is a [Bitwise or](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz3k228a.aspx), meaning that the `FILE_SHARE_ALL` should result with 7, since:

```
int 1 ' = binary 001
int 2 ' = binary 010
int 4 ' = binary 100  

001 | 010 | 100 = 111 ' equals int 7.
```